# count (*) with descending and random order

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having difficulty to get a output with especially with count(1) with descending & random value getting error. Please guide me where exactly I am missing!

testdb.mapping table contains multiple values of same src_owner, src_table_name so i need to sort those count of those in descending order (every time in a random fashion) so which ever count higher will pick up first & process, also in the same time need to filter those table_name & owner not in testdb.tab_copy_track table

```
 select *
 from (select table_name, owner
       from testdb.tab_info
       where copy_status = 'READY' and
             scope='TABLE_LEVEL' and
             (table_name, owner) not in (select table_name, owner
                                         from testdb.tab_copy_track
                                        ) and
             (table_name, owner) in ((select src_table_name, src_owner 
                                      from testdb.mapping
                                      group by src_table_name, src_owner                                           
                                      order by count(1) desc
                                     )
                                     ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
                                    )
             )
where rownum < 10;
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

sample data of testdb.mapping table

```
select src_table_name, src_owner from testdb.mapping group by src_table_name, src_owner order by count(1) desc

    SRC_TABLE_NAME               SRC_OWNER            COUNT(1)
    ---------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ----------
    CUSTOM_ENTITY_DATA_          TEST                    32149
    SEARCH_NAME_LOOKUP_          TEST                    10270
    ACCOUNT_CFDATA_              TEST                     9237
    ENTITY_HISTORY_              TEST                     8947
    CUSTOM_FOREIGN_KEY_VALUE_        TEST                     8299
    CONTACT_                 TEST                     7605
    DELETE_LOG_              TEST                     7253
    CUSTOM_INDEX_VALUE_          TEST                     6326
    CUST_IDX_VAL_DATE_NUM_           TEST                     6107
    CUSTOM_UNIQUE_VALUE_             TEST                     5953
    OPPORTUNITY_CFDATA_          TEST                     5849
    USER_LOGIN_              TEST                     5338
    CUST_IDX_VAL_STRING_NUM_         TEST                     5190
```

Comment: A bit strange why do you have this order by `ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` in the one of the select which is used for `in` clause. The order doesn't make any sense for such select statements.

Comment: What does your code have to do with your question?  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.  `ORDER BY` in an `IN` subquery is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used oracle tbh but would the following work?

```
select * from your_table order by dbms_random.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select *
from (select table_name, owner
      from testdb.tab_info
      where copy_status = 'READY' and
            scope = 'TABLE_LEVEL' and
            (table_name, owner) not in (select table_name, owner
                                        from testdb.tab_copy_track
                                        ) and
            (table_name, owner) in (select src_table_name, src_owner 
                                    from testdb.mapping                                     
                                   )
       order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
      )
where rownum < 10;
```

Comment: thanks for your comments !! testdb.mapping table contains multiple values of same src_owner, src_table_name so i need to sort those count of those in descending order (every time in a random fashion) so which ever count higher will pick up first & process, also in the same time need to filter those table_name & owner not in testdb.tab_copy_track table